# Excel VBA combobox disable problem

Tags: excel, vba, controls

I am trying to enable/disable a combobox based on the value or state of a second combobox in Excel 2007.

I think my code should look something like this:

```
Sub DropDown266_Change()
    If DropDown266.Index = 2 Then
        DropDown267.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub
```

However, I am getting a run time error '424' saying an object is required. I am sure this is a very simple change, but I can't seem to figure it out. Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Do both combo boxes exist on your form? In what line do you receive the error?

Comment: I am assuming both combo boxes exist. When right clicking on the boxes, their respective names appear in the "Name Box" in Excel. I have tried giving them their own unique names, but the same problem persists. Is there an easy way to list all of the objects on a worksheet/workbook, similar to the "Go To" button for named cells and objects?

The VBA error is on the first line, referring to DropDown266.

Comment: yes the only reason for this error to surface is unavailability of the object. Can you check the name of combo you want to disable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for getting the index is ComboBox1.ListIndex.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Me.DropDown266.Index

Also you can use Intellisense to check if the Combobox exists: type Me.Dro and see if DropDown266 appears in the list.